# Changing properties in a form from other classes

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I change a property in a windows form from another class' method?

Lets say I have Form1 with a label that says "Hello", if I want to change that message to something else using a method from another class, how can i refere to that label?

Comment: You can refer to it if you have an instance of the form. What does that class/method? Maybe you should simply return to the form what you want to see in the label. Then the form can update itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way - change your label visibility to `public` and pass `Form1` instance to that method. Correct one - declare public property `Message` on your `Form1` class like this:

```
public string Message
{
   get { return label.Text; }
   set { label.Text = value; }
}
```

And also pass instance of form to your method:

```
void MyMethod(Form1 form1)
{
    form1.Message = "Hello world";
}
```